# unable to insert data to database

Tags: php, mysql

Upload details to database but nothing inserted 
 `Unable to insert data to database`..

```
   $name  = $_POST['name'];
   $phon  = $_POST['phon'];
   $file  = $_POST['file'];
   $Email = $_POST['Email'];

   echo($name);
   echo($phon);        
   echo($file);

   echo($Email);

   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       # code...

       $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("couldnot connect");
   }

   mysql_select_db("vikash");

   mysql_query("INSERT into student (name,email,phon,photo) values ('$name','$Email','$phon','$file') ");
```

Comment: Firstly mysql_query is depreciated and you should use MySQLi or PDO. Secondly do you have any errors and do all your echos output as expected?

Comment: put all the codes inside the if block and try it again

Answer (score 0):

If your form is submitted successfully ,then the will be stored in your database. If is not working give me your latest situation.

//Check this

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phon = $_POST['phon'];
$file = $_POST['file'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("could not connect");
   mysqli_select_db("vikash");
   mysqli_query("INSERT into student (name,email,phon,photo) 
     values('$name','$Email','$phon','$file') ");
 }
```

Comment: May be he is a new programmer. For this reason I put this code according to his post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo the SQL/query on your php page, and than try to run the output on MySQL workbench.
And try to figure it from there it would be easier to pin point the issue.

Thanks,
Sambhav